# Notification in watchr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, notifications

I can't find an answer to a question. I would like to make a notification in watchr via autotest-notification, but I don't understand how to do it?
In Watchr Install section talks about libev. And I tried to do this in my Ubuntu10.10 but after start watchr notification not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. These issues I have been associated with [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/550566) on Ubuntu, when some program is running on full screen notify-send don't work.

Answer (score 1):

you have to install the libnotify-bin library and use the notify-send command in your scripts if you want to have gnome notifications ala MacOS

Comment: Yes. I have installed libnotify-bin, but I don't know How to use notify-send command in my scripts. Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad English.